# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and setRightBarButtonItem:animated:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiapplication

**TL;DR Update:** Basically what I need is to delay my code until iOS finishes its "app startup" animation.

I would like to animate content of a navigation bar when my app becomes active. In my controller, I'm subscribed to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and use `setRightBarButtonItem:animated:` to perform the change.

The problem is that the change is not animated.

I did some experimentation and discovered that if I wait a little (`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.3]`), it's animating without any issues.

Here is a simple view controller demonstrating the problem:

```
@interface TESTViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;

@end

@implementation TESTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationItem *item = [UINavigationItem new];
    UIBarButtonItem *oldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Old" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:NULL];
    [item setRightBarButtonItem:oldItem];
    [[self navigationBar] setItems:@[item] animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.3];
    UIBarButtonItem *newItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:NULL];
    [[[self navigationBar] items][0] setRightBarButtonItem:newItem animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I'd like find a better solution than blocking the thread or performing the change after a fixed delay.

Comment: Application becomes 'active' before view appears - why don't you simply move the animation code from `applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction` to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @rokjarc I'd love to. The thing is that `viewDidAppear:` is not being called when I switch back to the app. BTW, `viewDidAppear:` name is a bit misleading (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417318/viewdidappear-not-firing-ever-again-after-app-enters-foreground).

Comment: Ah, yes. i know i saw a workaround for that some time ago. I belive it had something to do with `UINavigationController` (even if it is not used in the view hierarchy). Will try to find it.

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past solved by using dispatch_async (onto the main queue) and performing the animation in that block. It adds no visible delay and doesn't block any threads. Might not work for your specific case, though.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `dispatch_after` on the main queue instead of calling
`+[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` class method.

Pass your animation as a block and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, this should work, since the changes will be performed _later_ – that means in some next update cycle. This is just a workaround, but since this has something to do with internal implementation, there is no _correct way_ of doing that.

Comment: it's not actually a workaround; it is indeed much better than using `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` because it will not block the UI thread. there are lots of times in terms of transitions that it is necessary to delay a small bit to allow in-process animation to complete so that your animation can properly start (and in the proper location).  and `dispatch_after()` (or `[obj performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`) is the way to do this without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

When posting notifications, I don't use your methods.

I use:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeButton) name:@"changeButton" object:nil];`

on the receiving end.

And on the posting end, I call 

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeButton" object:nil];`

Try moving your code to the method:

`-(void)changeButton{`

UIBarButtonItem *newItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:NULL];

```
[[[self navigationBar] items][0] setRightBarButtonItem:newItem animated:YES];
```

}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to performSelectorAfterDelay?

Try something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction:(NSNotification *)notification{
     [self performSelector:@selector(yourAnimationAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

- (void)yourAnimationAction{
    //Set your NavAnimation here
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:theItem animated:TRUE];
}
```

Just change the Delay to fit your apps wakeup delay... maybe this will take the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try by moving 
   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];`  to `viewDidLoad:` method. I think object is not registered for "`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`" while it is fired.

Answer (score -1):

Just call `viewDidAppear:` manually from within your `applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction:` method. Place your animation code in the `viewDidAppear:` method. Hope this helps.