# ViewDidAppear is not called when opening app from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a View Controller in which my value is 0 (label) and when I open that View Controller from another `ViewController` I have set `viewDidAppear` to set value 20 on label.  It works fine but when I close my app and than again I open my app but the value doesn't change because `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` nothing get called.  How can I call when I open my app.  Do I have to do anything from `applicationDidBecomeActive`?

Comment: You could post a local notification when application become active and add your view controller as observer and update values.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Curious about the exact sequence of events, I instrumented an app as follows:  (@Zohaib, you can use the NSNotificationCenter code below to answer your question).

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"app did become active");
}

// ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"did become active notification");
}

- (void)appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"will enter foreground notification");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view will appear");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view did appear");
}
```

At launch, the output looks like this:

```
2013-04-07 09:31:06.505 myapp[15459:11303] view did load
2013-04-07 09:31:06.507 myapp[15459:11303] view will appear
2013-04-07 09:31:06.511 myapp[15459:11303] app did become active
2013-04-07 09:31:06.512 myapp[15459:11303] did become active notification
2013-04-07 09:31:06.517 myapp[15459:11303] view did appear
```

Enter the background then reenter the foreground:

```
2013-04-07 09:32:05.923 myapp[15459:11303] app will enter foreground
2013-04-07 09:32:05.924 myapp[15459:11303] will enter foreground notification
2013-04-07 09:32:05.925 myapp[15459:11303] app did become active
2013-04-07 09:32:05.926 myapp[15459:11303] did become active notification
```

Comment: Danh, you mapped UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification to appDidEnterForeground:. Isn't that a bit misleading? Notice "will" and "did". Was that intentional?

Comment: @Lubiluk - not intentional.  I'll edit.  Good catch.

Comment: This was a very useful answer. I made a Swift version of it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34529572/3681880).

Comment: Perfect demonstration of background mode!

Comment: What are the sequence of events when you double tap on home button and close the app?

Comment: How can i do this in Xamarin iOS. Sorry I am really new to xamarin iOS.

Answer (score 141):

**Using Objective-C**

You should register a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method and whenever app comes back from background you can do whatever you want to do in the method registered for notification. `ViewController`'s **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear** won't be called when app comes back from background to foreground.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doYourStuff)

  name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)doYourStuff{

   // do whatever you want to do when app comes back from background.
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the notification you are registered for.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

**Note** if you register your `viewController` for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` then your method would be called every time your app becomes active, It is not recommended to register `viewController` for this notification .

**Using Swift**

For adding observer you can use the following code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "doYourStuff", name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
 }

 func doYourStuff(){
     // your code
 }
```

To remove observer you can use deinit function of swift.

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Yes it is :) sometimes it is difficult to find answers :)

Comment: @nsgulliver Do i have to manually invoke unregister the notification -(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
} . Will app do it for me?

Answer (score 43):

## Swift 3.0 ++ version

In your `viewDidLoad`, register at notification center to listen to this opened from background action

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(doSomething), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Then add this function and perform needed action

```
func doSomething(){
    //...
}
```

Finally add this function to clean up the notification observer when your view controller is destroyed.

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Easy and straight forward solution to handle the notification inside the VC +1

Comment: Can't believe this nice answer is missed in so many other similar/duplicate SO questions.

Answer (score 23):

### Swift 4.2. version

Register with the NotificationCenter in `viewDidLoad` to be notified when the app returns from background

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomething), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Implement the method that should be called.

```
@objc private func doSomething() {
    // Do whatever you want, for example update your view.
}
```

You can remove the observer once the `ViewController` is destroyed. This is only required below iOS9 and macOS 10.11

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: FYI I'm pretty sure you don't need to bother removing observers anymore these days...

Comment: @Fattie, I was hoping you'd provide a link to some official Apple documentation. Anyways, here it is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1407263-removeobserver#discussion. "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, and you used addObserver(_:selector:name:object:) to create your observer, you do not need to unregister the observer."

Answer (score 3):

Just have your view controller register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification and react accordingly.

Comment: How will i do that? i have called my viewController in applicationDidBecomeActive but. it overlap viewController or its fine to do that?

Comment: Don't call your viewController in applicationDidBecomeActive (which is wrong anyway because it gets called multiple times). Register for the notification in your `viewDidLoad` like @nsgulliver suggested. Your `viewDidAppear` will also call `doYourStuff` to set your label with the desired value.

Answer (score 3):

I think registering for the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is risky as you may end up with more than one controller reacting to that notification. Nothing garanties that these controllers are still visible when the notification is received.

Here is what I do: I force call viewDidAppear on the active controller directly from the App's delegate didBecomeActive method:

Add the code below to `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

```
UIViewController *activeController = window.rootViewController;
if ([activeController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    activeController = [(UINavigationController*)window.rootViewController topViewController];
}
[activeController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

Comment: It IS guaranteed if the controller unregisters (as it should) for the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification  in viewWillDisappear instead of in dealloc. Calling viewDidAppear explicitly looks like a hack to me, it breaks semantics (personal view) and can confuse people (from experience).

Answer (score 3):

try adding this in AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {        
    // makes viewWillAppear run
    self.window?.rootViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's documentation:

```
(void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

**Description:**
Tells a child controller its appearance is about to change.
If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that its views are about to **appear or disappear**. **Do not invoke `viewWillAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, or `viewDidDisappear:` directly**.

```
(void)endAppearanceTransition;
```

**Description:**

Tells a child controller its appearance has changed.
If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that the view transition is complete.

**Sample code:**

```
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [self.window.rootViewController beginAppearanceTransition: NO animated: NO];  // I commented this line

    [self.window.rootViewController endAppearanceTransition]; // I commented this line

}
```

Question: **How I fixed?**

**Ans**: I found this piece of lines in application. This lines made my app not recieving any ViewWillAppear notification's. **When I commented these lines it's working fine**.