# How to, applicationDidBecomeActive in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

How do I do this in Xamarin iOS?

[ViewDidAppear is not called when opening app from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864364/viewdidappear-is-not-called-when-opening-app-from-background)

The link below mentions the OnActivated method for Xamarin in the AppDelegate, but how do I subscribe my ViewController so it knows when the app comes from the background?

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10594/where-is-applicationdidbecomeactive-in-xamarin-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    NSObject notificationObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIApplication.DidBecomeActiveNotification, DoStuff);

    private void DoStuff (NSNotification a_notification)
    {
        // DO STUFF HERE
    }
```

Comment: Where did you end up putting this?  I keep getting an error that notificationObserver is assigned but its value is never used.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut I store my notificationObserver as a class level property and then on Dispose of the view controller I remove it: NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (this.notificationObserver);   But the critical part is the NSAction you pass in so it runs your code when that event fires.  In my case above it was "DoStuff"