# What comes first applicationWillResignActive app delegate method or the Notification for the same event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, lifecycle

In my app delegate I save(persist) an object when the `applicationWillResignActive:` method is called. I have a view controller which responds to `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and makes a modification to the previously mentioned object but doesn't save(persist) the object itself.
What I need to know is if that change will be persisted trough the `applicationWillResignActive:` method or if I should explicitly save it in the view controller just to be sure?

**Edit:** `NSLog` test result is: 1st is the delegate method, 2nd it is the Notification method.

I wasn't sure the test would guarantee me that the order will be the same every time because I don't know how notification center works. That is why I posted the question before testing and giving results.

Comment: What Object are you talking about here.

Comment: It is a `NSObject` which has `NSCoding` protocol implemented and is written to a file in order to save(persist) it.

Comment: @h3dkandi Just use `NSLog(...)` to find out. You can post the results as an answer below.

Comment: It would make a nice bookend with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15864784/294949

Comment: Did you test what happens before posting this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `applicationWillResignActive:` says, "After calling this method, the app also posts a UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notification to give interested objects a chance to respond to the transition."

The "after" makes me believe that you will not get the changed value inside `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Of course, inserting a couple of `NSLog` lines would let you prove the order of operation for yourself.