# I need to send a message to a method every time my app comes back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

It's a fullscreen app.

I have a method on `viewWillAppear` method that has to be called every time the apps comes from background.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self setUpVideo];
}
```

On `setUpVideo` I set up `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` because I lose the video when the apps come back from background.

As I have read, `viewWillAppear` isn't called when the apps come back from background and now, I don't know where to put that code.

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277940/why-does-viewwillappear-not-get-called-when-an-app-comes-back-from-the-backgroun), [occulus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348476/occulus) suggest to use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doMyLayoutStuff:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];` but it doesn't work for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setUpVideo:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
}
```

**Any advice?**

Comment: Please show your code where you use the notification!

Comment: @DrummerB 's answer is the way to do it. You could also use UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` instead.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
              selector:@selector(enterForeground:) 
              name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
              object:nil];
    // ...
}

- (void)enterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // do stuff
}
```

Don't call `viewWillAppear:` directly from the `enterForeground:` method. Instead move all required code to a separate method and call that from both `viewWillAppear:` and `enterForeground:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
applicationWillEnterForeground will trigger when app comes from background

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Additionally, you can use  `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` for firing some method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(handleMethod:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try posting this notification from 
`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` of AppDelegate(or observe corresponding notification which is better)