# Swift UILabel is nil (error) when app goes in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, viewdidload

I have some code that changes the text of a `UILabel`, it works fine when the app is run first time around but when I close it (app goes to background) and then I reopen it, the UILabel is `nil` and the text can't be set again.

The text is set to the UILabel in `viewDidLoad()` function and I call `viewDidLoad()` in `applicationWillEnterForeground` function to set the text to the `UILabel` again - that's when it crashes giving the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I debugged it and the `nil` found is the `UILabel`

Here is some of the code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) { 
     ViewController().refresh() 
}
```

And in `ViewController.swift`:

```
func refresh() {
    self.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Do you have any ideas why the `UILabel` becomes `nil` when the app goes to background?

Comment: You should never explicitly call `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` etc.  How are you getting the reference to the view controller in `applicationWillEnterForeground` ?  Please show the code in this method

Comment: Here is the function 
`func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        ViewController().refresh()
}` and in ViewController:
`func refresh() {
        self.viewDidLoad()
}`

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code - see the "edit" link under the tags.  What is `ViewController` - is it a property? How is it set?  Also you should refactor - never call `viewDidLoad` - if you want to re-use set up code then move that code to another function and have `viewDidLoad` call it

Comment: Ok I edited the question. I am not sure if the way I call the `refresh` function (present in the file `ViewController.swift`) is the correct way to do it..

Comment: Looks like you're creating a new `ViewController` instead of getting a reference to your existing one. This would explain why your label is `nil`.

Comment: I want to understand how `ViewController` gets its value (it should be `viewController` by the way - variables start with a small letter, classes with a capital) - I suspect that the contents of `ViewController` is an instance that isn't instantiated by your storyboard so you get nil for the IBOutlets

Comment: @AaronBrager @Paulw11 Yes you are right, but how do I create a reference to my `ViewController` then?

Comment: I would recommend that you don't.  Your view controller should subscribe to the events that are posted when your application becomes active - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680287/uiapplicationdidbecomeactive-vs-uiapplicationwillenterforeground-difference

Comment: Okay, so what is the code I have to put `applicationDidBecomeActive` (if I understand well, it is the best way) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to hold a reference to your view controller from your app delegate, it is better to simply have your view controller subscribe to the foreground entry event -

In your `viewDidLoad` add the following

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("enteringForeground:"),
  name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

The add a function to your ViewController

```
func enteringForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
   // Whatever you need to do to refresh UI
   // DO NOT CALL viewDidLoad
}

deinit {

   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

}
```

Comment: You should remove the observer before the view controller is deallocated. From the NSNotificationCenter docs: "You must invoke `removeObserver:` or `removeObserver:name:object:` before any object specified by `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` is deallocated."