# IOS Swift how reload viewcontroller when app come from background?

Tags: ios, swift

I want when user call app from background to reaload one function from viewcontroller?

Comment: use some flag value in NSUserdefault when in background mode and check if value set true then called and after call again set the flag to false hope make sense!!

Comment: if call from viewcontroller from background the function who calls again is viewdidload() ?

Comment: If anyone is looking for solution for swift 3 go here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529572/6595705

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register your controller for these notifications and reload your controller accordingly.

```
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

Comment: At AppDelage i had this functions and i had enable backgroud modes.

Comment: If you have implemented your functionality in those methods then, what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: sry this functions is in AppDelegate not at viewcontroller. This function observes the state of application inside the controller?

Comment: So you can register for these notifications in the viewDidLoad of your UIViewController and then you can handle these events in your UIViewController also

Comment: Thanks this resovle my problem .

Answer (score 9):

Elaborating on nishith's answer:

Add the following code to your view controller you want to refresh

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
......
......
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(YourViewController.methodToRefresh), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: UIApplication.shared)
......
......
}
```

Always remember to cleanup when the view disappears in:

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```