# Deselect table view row when returning to app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view and one of the table view cells opens another app. When I return to my app the table view cell is still highlighted. What is the best way to deselect a table view cell when returning to the app?

Edit: The issue is that `-viewWillAppear` or `-viewDidAppear` does not get called when returning from an app since the view is already visible.

Comment: You want never to select the item in tableView?

Comment: No, the item get's selected but it opens another app. I would like the deselect animation to occur when returning back to the original app.

Comment: @BerryBlue i get it, i want to know if you want the cell select at all? because you can never select the cell at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set notification in viewDidLoad

```
final override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // add notification observers
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}
```

Create method didBecomeActive

```
func didBecomeActive() {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**UIKit documentation**

- [UIApplicationDidBecomeActive](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622953-uiapplicationdidbecomeactive)
- [UITableView - indexPathForSelectedRow](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow)
- [UITableView - deselectRow](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow)

Comment: @Sneak chill out. It think my answer was accepted because it presented example code. Answer about notification i have from other ask:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277940/why-does-viewwillappear-not-get-called-when-an-app-comes-back-from-the-backgroun

Comment: Just because I point out some moral values to a free community where people use their valuable time to answer to problems for free doesnt mean I am not chill. Just a heads up for you, next time you copy a solution from an answer 1 hour later, make sure you atleast add a note giving the credit to the original solution that was posted 1 hour before yours. Nothing wrong with editing your answer to a **completely new one** based on another answer, however, make sure you credit the author, or the link you took the solution of if you say so.

Comment: Our answers are completely different. The only similarity is `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: @AdrianBobrowsku And Who pointed out to you that viewDidAppear does not get called? http://oi64.tinypic.com/2rmazpc.jpg That you had to change your answer 1 hour later? I don't see any comments here, oh yeah, thats right, my comment in my answer and my answer to this :) Im out, enjoy your "rep farming".

Comment: @Sneak What does this prove? And now you delete your answer. Why?

Comment: Dude, stop chatting now, I told you already, update your answer and give credit to the original author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277940/why-does-viewwillappear-not-get-called-when-an-app-comes-back-from-the-backgroun where you said you got the answer from. Thats all that I am asking. Let's stop the chat now. Also, I noted a couple downvotes on random answers of mine directly after your last comment and have contacted the moderators to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options for solve your issue

### Option 1

Deselect row in didSelectRow method
Example code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    // Open app code here
}
```

### Option 2

Find selected row and deselect row,

Put below code in ***viewDidAppear*** method

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```