# Why screen viewWillAppear is not calling when i back from browser in swift

Tags: ios, swift, safari, viewwillappear

I am calling my servicecall in viewWillAppear, and in same screen when i click on button webpage is opening in safari browser here when i go back to app from safari then my servicecall is not calling why?

**like this i am going back from safari to app**

[image]

**code:** here when i come back from webpage my `sellServiceCall` is not calling why?.. how to make it call when i back from safari web page.. guide me please

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
sellServiceCall()
}

@IBAction func connectStripeBtn(_ sender: Any) {

 stripeUrl = "someurl"
 UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: Your view doesn't "appear" when your apps is suspended and then returns to the foreground.  You will need to use the `didBecomeActive` notification in this case.  `viewWillAppear` is called when the view controller appears - is presented in your app

Comment: This should provide you with an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277940/why-does-viewwillappear-not-get-called-when-an-app-comes-back-from-the-backgroun

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you.. `didBecomeActive` notification will work when i come back from web page but My Question is: "this notification call will not effect when i come to that viewcontroller normally? i mean when i come from another viewcontroller to this viewcontroller not from web page.. in this case? "

Comment: @anySwift When you travel inside the application, between VCs, `viewWillAppear` will be called. It is for coming back into the app that this notification is required.

Answer (score 1):

When you travel inside the application, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` will be called each time the VC comes into view.

But, when you leave the app and it goes into "background", and then come back, it will never trigger `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear`. Because from the VC's point of view, you never left.

This is how you can listen to coming to foreground event, which also covers app launch:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: .main,
    using: { _ in
        // do your logic here
    }
)
```

If you need to update the VC when user comes back into foreground, you will need to listen to this event on that VC and execute your logic there.

Note: A better practice is not to listen to events directly on the VC, and instead find a way to propagate the event to the VC. Depends on your app's architecture.